# Case-Sensitive Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I can get user inputed name(username) with following code from a form. So my question is if i put `Shibbirbd` (First letter is Capital but it's `shibbirbd` in my database) then it's successfully go to user login panel! But it's wrong. why this happened?
Mysql Database username is: `shibbirbd`.

Login form script:

```
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['uname'])));
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pass'])));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `WHERE`clause to `WHERE BINARY` (`WHERE BINARY uname = '$uname'`) to test the binary value of the usernames against one another for equality.

If you would like all queries on this table to be case-sensitive, you should consider changing the collation, as [@Kolink suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671382/54680).

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you're expecting it to not log you in if you have uppercase letters where there should be lowercase?

In that case, change the collation of the table to something that's case-sensitive, such as `utf8_bin`.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the the strings are non casesensitive compaired. Why is it important that the username is casesensitive?

In MySQL you can see that with the encoding _ci which meanes case insensetive. Try some _bin or _cs formates if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the column collation is case-insensitive, which is the default. Try changing it to a case-sensitive collation, for example latine_general_cs

Answer (score 0):

Use `COLLATE` for case-sensitive.You see example in this link.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html